# How can I perform multi-tier ad-hoc aggregations based on filters provided by the user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My document schema looks something like this :

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "Y",
  Ethnicity: 'a',
  Zip: '06516'
},
{
  name: "Jane Doe",
  City : "CA",
  Prepaid: "N",
  Ethnicity: 'b'
  Zip: '12321'
},
{
  name: "Jule Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "N",
  Ethnicity: 'a'
  Zip: '06516'
},
{
  name: "Jake Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "Y",
  Ethnicity: 'a',
  zip: '06516'
}
```

I am trying to group them into multiple tiers and get the counts based on that. The only caveat is the filters for grouping arguments could be anything from the document.

What I wanna get will look something like this:

If the user selects to group them by City and Prepaid then it would look like this:

```
{
  City : OK
  Count : {
    "filter": prepaid,
    "count": {
      Y : 2
      N: 1
    }
  }
}

{
  City : CA
  Count : {
    "filter": prepaid,
    "count": {
      Y : 0
      N: 1
    }
  }
}
```

But if the user chooses Ethnicity and Prepaid it'd look something like this.

```
{

      Ethinicity : A,
      City: OK
      Count : {
        "filter": prepaid,
        "count": {
          Y : 2
          N: 1
        }
      }
    }
```

{

```
      Ethinicity : B,
      City: CA
      Count : {
        "filter": prepaid,
        "count": {
          Y : 1
          N: 0
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried doing this :

```
const countVals = await PhoneSamplingCollection.aggregate([
                        { $match: fullQuery },
                        {$group: groupquery //variable that has object provided by user to group on
                         , count:{$sum:1}}}
                    ]).exec();
```

It only gives me the count together and not the breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query :

**Updated Answer :**

If you've multiple options in **Prepaid** field to group on, then try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Group on city & prepaid & count no.of docs matches each criteria */
  {
    $group: { _id: { City: "$City", Prepaid: "$Prepaid" }, Count: { $sum: 1 } }
  },
  /** Group only on City to push all data to a field Count */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.City",
      Count: { $push: { k: "$_id.Prepaid", v: "$Count" } }
    }
  },
  /** Transform fields using project stage &
   *  use 'arrayToObject' to convert count array of objects to an object with {k:...,v:...} */
  { $project: { _id: 0, City: "$_id", Count: { $arrayToObject: "$Count" } } },
  { $project: { City: 1, Count: { count: "$Count", filter: "Prepaid" } } }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7UYgqgVc9wz)

**Old Answer :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$City",
      Y: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Prepaid", "Y"] }, 1, 0] } },
      N: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Prepaid", "N"] }, 1, 0] } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      City: "$_id",
      Count: { filter: "Prepaid", count: { Y: "$Y", N: "$N" } }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JLh5UyJ0ac0)

So in your code you would build queries based on user's selection & switch between based on conditions. Test below query, if you need `Ethinicity` as well.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        City: "$City",
        Ethnicity: "$Ethnicity"
      },
      Y: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Prepaid", "Y"] }, 1, 0] } },
      N: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Prepaid", "N"] }, 1, 0] } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      City: "$_id.City",
      Ethnicity: "$_id.Ethnicity",
      Count: { filter: "Prepaid", count: { Y: "$Y", N: "$N" } }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FB8MpD357vS)

Comment: Its easier for prepaid where there are just two options. Lets say there is a field called houseType which has six different categories. we'd have to do the same for all the fields.

Comment: @sajakupadhyaya : Try this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/7UYgqgVc9wz) which is more dynamic. Let me know if that works will update answer..

Comment: that solution I think was another of my question. I tried doing that.

Comment: @sajakupadhyaya: Your question is still unclear then, Please edit it with more info !!

Comment: I made a few adjustments and the updated answer helps me. If you dont mind me asking, what if there is three levels of nesting? Do I group the second group argument by two fields and then push the results on the final?

Comment: @sajakupadhyaya : Are you talking about `Enhancements` ? Yes something like that, you need to group on `City` & `Ehancements` - I can't visualize your data & give you a query which might not be better in real terms, maybe it would be helpful if you give me playground link & required o/p or raise a new question..

Comment: I have provided more information here, if you could take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978892/how-to-do-multi-tier-grouping-and-counts-for-dynamic-fields-in-mongo-db